# A question about Interrupt cycle FGI and FGO flipflops conditions - Basic Computer Organization and design

Tags: cpu-architecture

**Computer System Architecture - Morris Mano** In chapter 5 section 7 figure 5-13

[image: Figure 5-13]

When IEN it checks whether "FGI" or "FGO" are set to 1 then an interrupt cycle happens, but as I know is when FGI = 1 it means that information in INPR cannot be changed, and FGO is the reverse to that which means that when FGO is set to 1 then information in AC will be transferred to OUTR 'OUTR can be changed' so the question here **shouldn't the condition of applying interrupt cycle happen when "FGI" = 0 or "FGO" = 1 since INPR or OUTR can be changed under these conditions which now make since to execute an interrupt?**

Comment: For those of us who don't have that textbook, what do FGI and FGO stand for?

Comment: FGI is a flag flip flop associated with INPR when it's set to 1 then INPR register information cannot be changed - when it's set to 0 this means that AC has read the information of INPR and now INPR can accept new information -
FGO is a flag flip flop associated with OUTR register when it's set to 1 then information from AC is transferred to OUTR and flag is set to 0, as long as it's 0 then computer doesn't load any new information into OUTR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either flag being 1 logically means a device is "ready", but what "ready" means differs for input and for output devices.  In either case, flag being 1 means that the processor can or should now take action.

FGI=1 means the input device is ready, but that really means a new input is available (e.g. the user typed a key on a keyboard) and the processor should accept it.  FGO=1 prevents the input device(s) from overwriting a prior input held in INPR that the processor hasn't accepted yet.  When the processor accepts the input, FGI goes to 0 unlocking the INPR register, and that allows the input device to write again, which it will eventually do when the user presses another key (sending FGI back to 1 to signal the processor).

FGO=1 means ready for output, which really means the last output has been fully accepted by the device, so the OUTR register is unlocked for the processor to write a new data (character for the console).  FGO=0 prevents the processor from writing OUTR as the output device hasn't accepted the last one yet.

The interrupt service routine should check each flag, and if FGI=1 then accept an input (INPR->AC) and move it into a buffer for the user program to read when it is ready.  Whereas if FGO=1, then move an output character from memory buffer into the AC, and then do AC->OUTR, also lowering FGO to 0, which will preclude the processor writing until that data has been accepted by the device.

So, FGI=0 means that the processor has accepted the prior INPR value provided by the input device, and there is no new character as yet but the register is unlocked so the device can write at will.

FGO=0 means that the processor has written a value to the OUTR register, but the output device hasn't accepted that yet, so the register should be considered locked.

Comment: This a very clear explanation, thank you.